# SQL Delete duplicate rows with lowest number

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I can't find appropriate way to delete duplicate keys in sql table with lowest number. If there is a duplicate rows with the same Number, I need to delete one of them.

For example

```
Key     Number  Description

11111   5   Desc1
11111   4   Desc2
22222   2   Desc1
22222   2   Desc2
33333   3   Desc1
33333   5   Desc2
```

Here I need to be deleted the second row with Number 4 which is smaller then Number 5, one of the third or fourth row, and fifth row which have smaller Number 3 then the last row 5.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this - MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle ...?

Comment: is there another column ( like primary key ;-P )  to work with? that would make things easier without knowing your rdbms

Comment: This is a SQLServer.
Unfortunately I don't have primary key in the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query to remove duplicate in SQL-Server:

```
;with c as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by [Key] order by Number desc) as n
    from YouTable
)
delete from c
where n > 1
```

Comment: Wow!!!! I'm always amazed at how as well as I know SQL there are things I have no idea about. It keeps me humble.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM ztable dd
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM ztable ex
  WHERE ex.zkey = dd.zkey
  AND (ex.znumber > dd.znumber
       OR (ex.znumber = dd.znumber AND ex.description > dd.description)
       )
  );
```

Note: I renamed key and number to zkey and znumber to avoid confusion with reserved words/ keywords. Similar for ztable.