# How to delete a duplicate record without using primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I went for an interview today where they give me technical test on sql. One of them was how to delete duplicate records without a primary key.

For one I can't imagine a table without a primary key. Yes I have read the existing threads on this. Say this happened and needed to be fixed Now. Couldn't I just add to the end of the table a automatically  incrementing id then use that to delete the duplicate record?

Can anyone think of a reason why that won't work? I tried it on a simple database I created and I can't see any problems

Comment: Did they specify a specific RDBMS such as MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: They used a sql server backend

Comment: The answer is heavily dependent on RDBMS. Most databases let you delete by a "synthetic" row identifier, rather than requiring you to add a column explicitly.

Comment: Adding unique constraint and delete records based on it will definitely work . However, I guess they expected solution that don't require ddl . As far as I remember, SQLServer allows specifying `TOP` in `DELETE`.

Comment: Here is [an answer for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15742649/335858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of options here.

If they don't mind you dropping the table you could `SELECT DISTINCT *` from the table in question and then `INSERT` this into a new table, `DROP`ping the old table as you go. This obviously won't be usable in a Production database but can be useful for where someone has mucked up a routine that's populating a data warehouse for example.

Alternatively you could effectively create a temporary index by using the row number as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742649/335858). That answer shows you how to use the built in `row_number()` function in SQL server but could be replicated in other RDBMS' (not sure which but MySQL certainly) by declaring a variable called `@row_num` or equivalent and then using it in your `SELECT` statement as:

```
SET @row_num=0;
SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS row_num, [REMAINING COLUMNS GO HERE]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible options how to do this:

1. select distinct rows from your table(you can achieve this using group by all columns)
2. insert result into new table
3. drop first table
4. alter second table to name of first one

But this is not always possible in production